# In Flask, how to make all subroutes pass also through the common parent route?

Tags: python, flask

I have routes for my rest service:

```
localhost/rest/get/user
localhost/rest/get/logs/username
localhost/rest/post/user
```

etc.
I have them registered as blueprints like so:

```
app.register_blueprint(rest, url_prefix="/rest")
app.register_blueprint(rest_get, url_prefix="/rest/get")
app.register_blueprint(rest_post, url_prefix="/rest/post")
```

I want however, that both the `/rest/get` routes and `/rest/post` routes all pass also through the common `/rest` route so that I can add some before_request checks to them. However this is not the case per default, the Flask just routes the request to the most specific one. How do I make it also look in to the parent route? So in `rest.py` I have:

```
@rest.before_request
@jwt_required(locations=["headers"])
def before_request():
    print("************************************************* in rest in before_request")
    pass
```

However, it is ignored and just goes to the one in rest_get.py, which is:

```
rest_get = Blueprint("rest_get", __name__)

@rest_get.before_request
@jwt_required(locations=["headers"])
def before_request():
    print("************************************ in rest_get in before_request")
    pass
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you perform certain operations in the common route and you would want your subroutes to perform these operations before executing the function corresponding to the subroute.

The easiest thing I can think of if to implement the common operation as a separate class or function and call it in every route, subroute etc

For example

```
@app.route("/rest")
def base():
    response = common_operation()
    return response.json()

@app.route("/rest/sr1")
def subroute1():
    op = common_operation()
    op1 = further_operations(op)
    return op1
```

Something like this is what I do and suggest the same.

Comment: I actually already do something like that, yes. But, I would love to refactor it so that for all family of subroutes, I only call that method once. I am guessing it can be done somehow in parent route, but I don't know how....